# fobs4jmf.dll Error in Java Swing playing .avi videos

Tags: java, swing, jmf, avi

I recently started helping a colleague with debugging a video crash issue with her Java Swing application. The application makes a native call to fobs4jmf.dll for playing .avi files. Sometimes, not always, the native code crashes the application. I didn't write the original application and the engineer that did is long gone; could anyone provide some insight? The error file is as follows:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6b1d7994, pid=4716, tid=3572
#
# JRE version: 6.0_24-b07
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (19.1-b02 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [fobs4jmf.dll+0x257994]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x1f0ca400):  JavaThread "Loop thread: com.omnividea.media.parser.video.VideoTrack@19a403a" [_thread_in_native, id=3572, stack(0x20670000,0x206c0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x1d961000

Registers:
EAX=0x00000268, EBX=0x0000004d, ECX=0x00000268, EDX=0x1d960fb0
ESP=0x206bf7b0, EBP=0x206bf8f8, ESI=0x0000002a, EDI=0x206bf980
EIP=0x6b1d7994, EFLAGS=0x00210216

Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x00000268
0x00000268 is pointing to unknown location

EBX=0x0000004d
0x0000004d is pointing to unknown location

ECX=0x00000268
0x00000268 is pointing to unknown location

EDX=0x1d960fb0
0x1d960fb0 is pointing to unknown location

ESP=0x206bf7b0
0x206bf7b0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x1f0ca400
"Loop thread: com.omnividea.media.parser.video.VideoTrack@19a403a" prio=4 tid=0x1f0ca400 nid=0xdf4 runnable [0x206bf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

EBP=0x206bf8f8
0x206bf8f8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x1f0ca400
"Loop thread: com.omnividea.media.parser.video.VideoTrack@19a403a" prio=4 tid=0x1f0ca400 nid=0xdf4 runnable [0x206bf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

ESI=0x0000002a
0x0000002a is pointing to unknown location

EDI=0x206bf980
0x206bf980 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x1f0ca400
"Loop thread: com.omnividea.media.parser.video.VideoTrack@19a403a" prio=4 tid=0x1f0ca400 nid=0xdf4 runnable [0x206bf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE


Top of Stack: (sp=0x206bf7b0)
0x206bf7b0:   1d90c0d0 1d90c0d0 1d90c0cb 00000268
0x206bf7c0:   00000001 001d0000 1d960fb0 206bf714
0x206bf7d0:   001dfe80 206bfdf8 77631ecd 052d84dc
0x206bf7e0:   44697658 36343030 b8b7b6b4 5a01abb8
0x206bf7f0:   13570500 a95fe803 90dfe81d 8400381d
0x206bf800:   90dff01d 9610001d 775f001d 00000111
0x206bf810:   00000120 001dfe7a 001dfe78 000004d0
0x206bf820:   00000111 775ee026 1f0ca518 206bf898 

Instructions: (pc=0x6b1d7994)
0x6b1d7984:   95 d0 fe ff ff 89 c3 89 85 c4 fe ff ff c1 fb 03
0x6b1d7994:   8b 04 13 8b 9d c4 fe ff ff 83 e3 07 89 c2 88 d9 


Stack: [0x20670000,0x206c0000],  sp=0x206bf7b0,  free space=317k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [fobs4jmf.dll+0x257994]
C  [fobs4jmf.dll+0x251bbc]
C  [fobs4jmf.dll+0x19c44a]
C  [fobs4jmf.dll+0x54b4a]
C  [fobs4jmf.dll+0x59b6]
C  [fobs4jmf.dll+0x5d4d]
C  [fobs4jmf.dll+0x1483]
j  com.omnividea.media.parser.video.Parser.avProcess(ILjava/lang/Object;JJZI)Z+0
j  com.omnividea.media.parser.video.Parser.getNextFrame(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)Z+15
j  com.omnividea.media.parser.video.VideoTrack.readFrame(Ljavax/media/Buffer;)V+170
j  com.sun.media.SourceThread.process()Z+206
j  com.sun.media.util.LoopThread.run()V+14
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0xf0ab9]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1837d1]
V  [jvm.dll+0xf0c61]
V  [jvm.dll+0xf0cbb]
V  [jvm.dll+0x11b4b9]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1e4624]
V  [jvm.dll+0x18317c]
C  [msvcr71.dll+0x9565]
C  [kernel32.dll+0x1339a]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x39ed2]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x39ea5]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.omnividea.media.parser.video.Parser.avProcess(ILjava/lang/Object;JJZI)Z+0
j  com.omnividea.media.parser.video.Parser.getNextFrame(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)Z+15
j  com.omnividea.media.parser.video.VideoTrack.readFrame(Ljavax/media/Buffer;)V+170
j  com.sun.media.SourceThread.process()Z+206
j  com.sun.media.util.LoopThread.run()V+14
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x1f0cac00 JavaThread "Loop thread: com.omnividea.media.parser.video.AudioTrack@1eed80d" [_thread_blocked, id=4472, stack(0x20700000,0x20750000)]
=>0x1f0ca400 JavaThread "Loop thread: com.omnividea.media.parser.video.VideoTrack@19a403a" [_thread_in_native, id=3572, stack(0x20670000,0x206c0000)]
  0x1f0ca000 JavaThread "Loop thread: com.sun.media.renderer.audio.JavaSoundRenderer@df2acf" [_thread_blocked, id=1248, stack(0x205e0000,0x20630000)]
  0x1f0c9800 JavaThread "Java Sound Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3876, stack(0x20130000,0x20180000)]
  0x1f0c9400 JavaThread "Loop thread: com.omnividea.media.renderer.video.Java2DRenderer@75460" [_thread_blocked, id=4848, stack(0x1f770000,0x1f7c0000)]
  0x1f0c8c00 JavaThread "JMF thread: com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@1c84697 ( prefetchThread)" [_thread_blocked, id=2516, stack(0x1f6e0000,0x1f730000)]
  0x1f0c8800 JavaThread "JMF thread: com.sun.media.content.unknown.Handler@6c0227 ( prefetchThread)" [_thread_blocked, id=1392, stack(0x1f650000,0x1f6a0000)]
  0x1f0c8000 JavaThread "JMF thread (PlayThread)" [_thread_blocked, id=4136, stack(0x1f5c0000,0x1f610000)]
  0x1f0c7c00 JavaThread "Image Fetcher 1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4552, stack(0x1f530000,0x1f580000)]
  0x1f0c7400 JavaThread "Image Fetcher 0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3700, stack(0x1de80000,0x1ded0000)]
  0x1f0c7000 JavaThread "Loop thread" [_thread_blocked, id=4980, stack(0x1f4a0000,0x1f4f0000)]
  0x1f0a7400 JavaThread "JMF thread: SendEventQueue: com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine" [_thread_blocked, id=4832, stack(0x1d7d0000,0x1d820000)]
  0x18b10800 JavaThread "JMF thread: SendEventQueue: com.sun.media.content.unknown.Handler" [_thread_blocked, id=3480, stack(0x1d740000,0x1d790000)]
  0x18c22000 JavaThread "TimerQueue" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4992, stack(0x1fae0000,0x1fb30000)]
  0x18c14000 JavaThread "D3D Screen Updater" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3612, stack(0x1cb60000,0x1cbb0000)]
  0x00609400 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=2620, stack(0x00250000,0x002a0000)]
  0x18c0c000 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_blocked, id=1912, stack(0x1cad0000,0x1cb20000)]
  0x18b63400 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2740, stack(0x19020000,0x19070000)]
  0x18b18000 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=1584, stack(0x18f30000,0x18f80000)]
  0x18b17800 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4588, stack(0x18ea0000,0x18ef0000)]
  0x02530400 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2596, stack(0x189b0000,0x18a00000)]
  0x0252c000 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2984, stack(0x18920000,0x18970000)]
  0x0252b000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2932, stack(0x18890000,0x188e0000)]
  0x02528000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=932, stack(0x18800000,0x18850000)]
  0x024f9800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4872, stack(0x18770000,0x187c0000)]
  0x024f8400 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=700, stack(0x186e0000,0x18730000)]

Other Threads:
  0x024f3400 VMThread [stack: 0x18690000,0x186e0000] [id=4380]
  0x0253ac00 WatcherThread [stack: 0x18a40000,0x18a90000] [id=4388]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 1445K [0x045e0000, 0x04b30000, 0x09b30000)
  eden space 4416K,  29% used [0x045e0000, 0x04720710, 0x04a30000)
  from space 512K,  32% used [0x04a30000, 0x04a590b0, 0x04ab0000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x04ab0000, 0x04ab0000, 0x04b30000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 3317K [0x09b30000, 0x0a5e0000, 0x145e0000)
   the space 10944K,  30% used [0x09b30000, 0x09e6d4d8, 0x09e6d600, 0x0a5e0000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 10958K [0x145e0000, 0x151e0000, 0x185e0000)
   the space 12288K,  89% used [0x145e0000, 0x15093a00, 0x15093a00, 0x151e0000)
No shared spaces configured.

Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x00424000     C:\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe
0x775c0000 - 0x77740000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
0x764d0000 - 0x765e0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
0x76400000 - 0x76446000     C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
0x76920000 - 0x769c0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\ADVAPI32.dll
0x76a60000 - 0x76b0c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
0x762a0000 - 0x762b9000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
0x761a0000 - 0x76290000     C:\Windows\syswow64\RPCRT4.dll
0x75120000 - 0x75180000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SspiCli.dll
0x75110000 - 0x7511c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x7c340000 - 0x7c396000     C:\Java\jre6\bin\msvcr71.dll
0x6d7f0000 - 0x6da96000     C:\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x76e20000 - 0x76f20000     C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
0x765e0000 - 0x76670000     C:\Windows\syswow64\GDI32.dll
0x76290000 - 0x7629a000     C:\Windows\syswow64\LPK.dll
0x76d10000 - 0x76dad000     C:\Windows\syswow64\USP10.dll
0x734c0000 - 0x734f2000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x76db0000 - 0x76e10000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x760d0000 - 0x7619c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\MSCTF.dll
0x74d10000 - 0x74d5c000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x6d7a0000 - 0x6d7ac000     C:\Java\jre6\bin\verify.dll
0x6d320000 - 0x6d33f000     C:\Java\jre6\bin\java.dll
0x6d280000 - 0x6d288000     C:\Java\jre6\bin\hpi.dll
0x77590000 - 0x77595000     C:\Windows\syswow64\PSAPI.DLL
0x6d7e0000 - 0x6d7ef000     C:\Java\jre6\bin\zip.dll
0x6d000000 - 0x6d14a000     C:\Java\jre6\bin\awt.dll
0x74fe0000 - 0x75031000     C:\Windows\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
0x75f70000 - 0x760cc000     C:\Windows\syswow64\ole32.dll
0x71830000 - 0x719ce000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\COMCTL32.dll
0x763a0000 - 0x763f7000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SHLWAPI.dll
0x74590000 - 0x745a3000     C:\Windows\system32\DWMAPI.DLL
0x747b0000 - 0x74830000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x6d230000 - 0x6d27f000     C:\Java\jre6\bin\fontmanager.dll
0x74370000 - 0x74533000     C:\Windows\system32\d3d9.dll
0x75040000 - 0x75049000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x74360000 - 0x74366000     C:\Windows\system32\d3d8thk.dll
0x70420000 - 0x70f9f000     C:\Windows\system32\nvd3dum.dll
0x72420000 - 0x72445000     C:\Windows\system32\powrprof.dll
0x76f20000 - 0x770bd000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SETUPAPI.dll
0x75180000 - 0x751a7000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CFGMGR32.dll
0x767b0000 - 0x7683f000     C:\Windows\syswow64\OLEAUT32.dll
0x762f0000 - 0x76302000     C:\Windows\syswow64\DEVOBJ.dll
0x75320000 - 0x75f6a000     C:\Windows\syswow64\shell32.dll
0x6d600000 - 0x6d613000     C:\Java\jre6\bin\net.dll
0x768d0000 - 0x76905000     C:\Windows\syswow64\WS2_32.dll
0x76910000 - 0x76916000     C:\Windows\syswow64\NSI.dll
0x72530000 - 0x7256c000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x723b0000 - 0x723b6000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x6d620000 - 0x6d629000     C:\Java\jre6\bin\nio.dll
0x6af80000 - 0x6b671000     C:\Users\Nightshade\Desktop\UNCG\lib\fobs4jmf.dll
0x6d510000 - 0x6d534000     C:\Java\jre6\bin\jsound.dll
0x6d540000 - 0x6d548000     C:\Java\jre6\bin\jsoundds.dll
0x1fbc0000 - 0x1fc32000     C:\Windows\system32\DSOUND.dll
0x71020000 - 0x71059000     C:\Windows\system32\MMDevAPI.DLL
0x74010000 - 0x74105000     C:\Windows\system32\PROPSYS.dll
0x6ef90000 - 0x6efc0000     C:\Windows\system32\wdmaud.drv
0x6efd0000 - 0x6efd4000     C:\Windows\system32\ksuser.dll
0x6efc0000 - 0x6efc7000     C:\Windows\system32\AVRT.dll
0x6ed30000 - 0x6ed66000     C:\Windows\system32\AUDIOSES.DLL
0x6ef80000 - 0x6ef88000     C:\Windows\system32\msacm32.drv
0x74340000 - 0x74354000     C:\Windows\system32\MSACM32.dll
0x6ef70000 - 0x6ef77000     C:\Windows\system32\midimap.dll
0x76310000 - 0x76393000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CLBCatQ.DLL

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dconf.path=conf/ -Djava.library.path=lib 
java_command: util.Main
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
CLASSPATH=C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\Nightshade\bin;C:\Python27;C:\Program Files (x86)\Mercurial\bin;C:\Java\jre6\bin;C:Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Users\Nightshade\android-sdk-windows;C:\apache-ant-1.8.2\bin
USERNAME=Nightshade
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 4 (4 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 23 stepping 7, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1

Memory: 4k page, physical 4192824k(2803136k free), swap 8383800k(6544444k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (19.1-b02) for windows-x86 JRE (1.6.0_24-b07), built on Feb  2 2011 17:44:41 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 7.1 (VS2003)

time: Sat Nov 05 18:25:20 2011
elapsed time: 156 seconds
```

The error apparently first came about when her systems were migrated to Windows 7 from Windows XP (you may begin cursing silently and shaking your hand at IT departments everywhere); but reverting the machines back to Windows XP didn't fix the problem.

It is also worth reiterating that this error doesn't always occur! Sometimes the application runs fine and sometimes it crashes when starting the native JMF code.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

such error generally occurs when system don't have dll file support, so try to check 
  dll support for your corresponding player or

download any application which fills the necessary dll files in your system try